# How to forward domain to meteor deployed website (using GoDaddy)?

Tags: meteor

This seems simple enough, but its not quite working.

I have a website deployed at website.meteor.com and it seems to work just fine.

I have a domain name, website.com with GoDaddy. There's some weird business with the www that I'm unclear about, but it seems I'm "forwarding" website.com to www.website.com. I had no idea there's a difference. Anyways, I think (hope) this is unrelated.

In my Domain, DNS Zone Files, I set the CNAME (alias) to point to website.meteor.com. This didn't work. I get that the meteor website is down. But when I go to website.meteor.com, it seems to be just fine.

I realized that www.website.meteor.com doenst work, so I suspect maybe thats the issue?

In my CNAME (alias), I realized that HOST is www so maybe thats the issue. I deleted that, but then I couldn't save with no host. It says the host is the "subdomain in which the record applies", whatever that means. So I tried putting website there, "Points to" meteor.com. Well that didn't work either.

Hopefully there something very minor I'm messing up here.

Comment: hmm. what's this origin.meteor.com? http://docs.meteor.com/#deploying

Answer (score 3):

OK, I figured it out.

Host: "website"
CNAME: "origin.meteor.com"

Thats not enough though. I've already deployed to website.meteor.com but it doesn't show up.

You then have to `mrt deploy www.website.com`.